# Multiple paths/files with Nodesjs / Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Currently I have a chat-tool made out of the example from SocketIO for Node.js

But now I want to implement a view who only watches. But my problem is that I cant create / I dont know how to create multiple file pathes. Currently im connecting to the chat app via localhost:3000.

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Is it possible to create another path to get to with like localhost:3000/viewOnly.html ?

If yes how would you do it?

Comment: You should probably have a look at the express documentation and maybe some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it myself.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/ViewOnly.html',function (req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/ViewOnly.html');
})
```